# Is there a graphlab equivalent to df.irow?

Tags: pandas, graphlab

I need to pick out a few rows in my sframe by index.  Is there an equivalent graphlab command to pandas df.irow()?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent in graphlab to `DataFrame.iloc` (previously `irow`). One way to achieve the same thing is to add a column of row numbers and use the `filter_by` method. Suppose I want to get only the 1st and 3rd rows:

```
import graphlab
sf = graphlab.SFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']})
sf = sf.add_row_number('row_id')
new_sf = sf.filter_by(values=[0, 2], column_name='row_id')
```